# Looking for a "romantic" movie or tv movie from 80's to early 90's about a young photographer

Tags: identify-this-movie, romance

My sister's birthday is coming up, and a few weeks ago she and I ended up talking about a film we had seen over 20 years ago. Neither she nor I could remember the name of the film, or the actors.

The only thing we remembered was that it was a film about a boy (I think he might have been a teenager) who was photographing stuff, and he was at this pier or harbor and took some pictures. When he finally got home and developed the pictures he had taken, he noticed a girl in one of the pictures, whom he had not noticed while taking the photo.

I think he then responds holy shit, because he thought she was drop dead gorgeous or something, and he tries to find her, which he eventually does, but I think she was already in a relationship or something and that this movie does not have a happy ending.

This is about everything any of us could remember, but my sister sounded like she really wanted to see this film again, so if I could find out what film this was, I could buy it for her birthday.

The movie was in English.

Does anyone have any clue what film this is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like [No Small Affair](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087810/combined) from 1984 with Jon Cryer and Demi Moore.

> The 16 years old amateur photographer Charles accidentally takes a photo of Laura - and falls in love with her, when he develops the picture. He finds out that she works as singer in a bar, but is about to be thrown out. Although rejected at first by the 23 years old, he wants to help her and starts an ad campaign behind her back... with unexpected results.

He shoots that photo of her in a harbor. Here's the trailer:

Comment: Yes this is it! :D Thanks man. My sister will never see this gift coming. :D:D

Comment: @Mandsome unless she happens to stumble on this thread ;) xD

Comment: @Olle oh lol. Yeah chances of that are rather small. :D And i found it on dvd on amazon, rather cheap too. It's on it's way in the mail right now... (Who am i kidding, it's gonna take them weeks). But i will tell my sister i walked across continents to acquire this, i had to fight crocodiles and savage hippos. And inside a dark cave in the deepest corners of the amazon i found it, on a pedestal, guarded by a menacing turtle by the name of James... Good plan.